# Why is the Fibonacci ratio though a decreasing function, it is alternating and decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, fibonacci-numbers

I tried to find the ratio of consecutive terms of the Fibonacci series and found that it is a decreasing function and it converges .
I tried it though a small code piece in python so that I can have a lot of data points to analyze.

```
import math

def F(n):
    return ((1+math.sqrt(5))**n-(1-math.sqrt(5))**n)/(2**n*math.sqrt(5))

for i in range(53):
    a = F(i)
    b = F(i+1)

print str(b) + '/' + str(a) + '=>' + str(b/a)
```

And it gave values which suggested that it is a decreasing function and it converges at around 1.618. But I found that, though it was decreasing, it was not a continuously decreasing function, it in fact increases and decreases alternatively. But overall it was decreasing and converging.

And I tried to plot the values to prove this graphically.
[image]

(I expanded the graph a bit by plotting for $n*3$, just to make the view clear)

**My doubt is this - What is so special in this series which makes it behave alternating in nature?**

I tried to do it for consecutive numbers ratio and found that it was a increasing but not alternating like the Fibonacci ratios.

Thanks

Comment: Yes , I have used it here .Is there anything wrong .Sorry. If wrong please correct me .

Comment: This is correct. An explanation can be given by studying Binet's formula or from the theory of convergents of a continued fraction.

Comment: If so please enlighten me on this .And please explain it based on the ratios (just by numbers) and why these ratio's are so .

Comment: Please give it as an answer and don't give in comments section

Comment: I'm confused here– is the question "why does the series alternate?", "why does the series converge?", or both?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The series is alternately greater than/less than its ultimate limit, and the absolute difference from the limit reduces at each stage.

Comment: I have made the question in bold . To repeat , I am asking "why does the series alternate and decrease instead of just decreasing?". Ya it should be surely decreasing as it has larger numbers in denominators.

Comment: Which ratio are you looking at? F(i+1)/F(i) or F(i)/F(i+1)? The program and the limit (0.618...) suggests latter, but the graph corresponds to the former.

Comment: Sorry you are right . I will edit .

Comment: "it should be surely decreasing as it has larger numbers in denominators" - by that logic, it should surely be increasing as it has increasingly large numbers in the numerator too.

Comment: But increase in denominator is  greater(far greater) than increase in numerator  as series series goes expanding

Comment: Going from $F_{n+1}/F_n$ to $F_{n+2}/F_{n+1}$ increases the numerator by $F_n$ and the denominator by $F_{n-1}$. That is, we're actually always increasing the *numerator* more than we are increasing the denominator. But that doesn't mean much. For instance, $5/2>3/1$ is false even though the increase from $3$ to $5$ is greater than the increase from $1$ to $2$. Whether or not $a/b>c/d$ is not determined by if $a-c>b-d$.

Comment: Ya .You are right , my reasoning was wrong in the above comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of approaching the question *via* continued fractions, one can look at the closed form solution of the recurrence $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ with initial values $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$: this is given by the [*Binet formula*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)

$$F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}{\sqrt5}\;,$$

where $\varphi$ and $\widehat\varphi$ are respectively the positive and negative solutions of the quadratic $x^2-x-1=0$,

$$\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\approx1.618\quad\text{and}\quad\widehat\varphi=\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\approx-0.681\;.$$

Thus, for the ratio we have

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{\varphi^{n+1}-\widehat\varphi^{n+1}}{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}=\varphi+\frac{\varphi\widehat\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^{n+1}}{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}=\varphi+\frac{\widehat\varphi^n(\varphi-\widehat\varphi)}{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}=\varphi+\frac{\widehat\varphi^n\sqrt5}{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}\;,$$

so that

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\varphi=\frac{\sqrt5}{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}\cdot\widehat\varphi^n\;.$$

The factor $\dfrac{\sqrt5}{\varphi^n-\widehat\varphi^n}$ is always positive; $\widehat\varphi^n$ is positive for even $n$ and negative for odd $n$, so

$$\begin{cases}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}>\varphi,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\\\
\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}<\varphi,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

This clearly implies the alternating behavior of the ratio:

$$\frac{F_2}{F_1}<\varphi<\frac{F_3}{F_2}>\varphi>\frac{F_4}{F_3}<\varphi<\frac{F_5}{F_4}>\varphi>\frac{F_6}{F_5}<\ldots\;.$$

Answer (score 10):

Consider the formula you used for calculating the values: $$F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\phi^n - \psi^n\right)$$ where $\phi=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sqrt{5}\right)$ and $\psi=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)$.

The ratio of consecutive terms can then be expressed as $$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-\psi^{n+1}}{\phi^n - \psi^n} = \phi + \frac{(\phi-\psi)\psi^n}{\phi^n -\psi^n}$$

There are is a couple of observations we can now make:

- We have $|\phi|>1$ and $|\psi|<1$. Thus, with increasing $n$, the value of $\psi^n$ will get closer and closer to zero, while $\phi^n$ will grow further and further. This already implies the ratio $(F_{n+1}/F_n)$ converges to $\phi$, since the other term converges to zero (its numerator is going to zero and denominator to infinity).
- $\psi<0$, so $\psi^n$ flips its sign whenever we increase $n$ by one. Therefore, the second term oscillates from positives to negatives; making the ratio alternate between being greater than $\phi$ and smaller than $\phi$.

The first observation can be generalized to any sequence which can be expressed as a linear combination of exponentials, the greatest of which has base greater (in absolute value) than 1. The ratio of consecutive terms will converge to this greatest base.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a complete answer to your question, but this is a feature of continued fractions - and the Fibonacci Sequence can be generated in this way.

Amongst other sources try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) and [this](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfINTRO.html). Hardy and Wright "Introduction to the Theory of Numbers" has a pretty good introduction too.

Answer (score 5):

This is a general property of [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) convergents.

Recall that simple infinite or finite continued fractions are represented by

$$[a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n]:=a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{\cdots+\cfrac{1}{a_n}}}}$$

$$[a_0,a_1,a_2,\cdots]:=a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{\cdots}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}[a_0,\cdots,a_n].$$

If $x=[a_0,\cdots]$ then the rationals $[a_0,\cdots,a_n]$ are called $x$'s partial convergents.

Observe that as $x$ increases, $x^{-1}$ decreases, so $(c+x^{-1})^{-1}$ increases, and so on. Inductively, then, we can conclude that increasing $a_i$ increases $[a_0,\cdots]$ (finite or infinite) if $i$ is even and decreases its value if $i$ is odd. Usually we want the $a_i$ to be natural numbers (except maybe the first) so we get unique representations and can look into arithmetic-diophantine properties of the real number line, but technically we don't need to. So we have

$$[a_0,\cdots,a_n]=[a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}+a_n^{-1}]\quad \begin{cases}\ge [a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}] & n~\rm even \\ \le [a_0,\cdots,a_{n-1}] & n~\rm odd.\end{cases}$$

since $a_{n-1}\to a_{n-1}+a_n^{-1}$ amounts to increasing $a_{n-1}$.

Another induction argument shows that each convergent of $x$ is closer to $x$ than the last. In fact we have the following two infinite lists of inequalities:

$$[a_0,a_1]> [a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3]>[a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5]>\cdots > x$$

$$x>\cdots\cdots\cdots> [a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4]>[a_0,a_1,a_2]>[a_0].$$

That is, the values of the partial convergents of $x$ "zig-zag" ever closer to the true value of $x$ from below and above (we are assuming that $x$ has an infinite continued fraction expansion).

It is well-known that the golden ratio $\varphi$ has the continued fraction expansion $[1,1,1,\cdots]$, and furthermore that the partial convergents are the ratio of successive Fibonacci numbers, which is to say that $[\underbrace{1,1,\cdots,1}_n]=F_{n+1}/F_n$. Thus the fact of oscillation follows.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the Fibonacci numbers as starting with $1,1,2,3,5,\dots$. Call these $a_1, a_2.a_3,a_4, a_5,\dots$.

Note that $a_3a_1-a_2^2=1$, $a_4a_2-a_3^2=-1$, and $a_5a_3-a_4^2 =-1$. This nice pattern *continues forever*. We prove that  later, and race to the finish.

So $a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2$ alternates forever between positive and negative values.

When  $a_{n+2}a_n -a_{n+1}^2$ is positive, we have $a_{n+2}a_n \gt a_{n+1}^2$. Divide both sides by $a_na_{n+1}$. We get
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}} \gt \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$
This says that the 'next" ratio is **bigger** than the previous ratio.

Similarly, when   $a_{n+2}a_n -a_{n+1}^2$ is negative,
$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}} \lt \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}.$$
This says that the next ratio is **less** than the previous ratio.

We have shown that the  alternation you observed indeed takes place, **if** the signs really do alternate. We now show that they do.

**Proof of Alternation of Signs:** Start from the expression $a_{n+2}a_n -a_{n+1}^2$, replace $a_{n+2}$ by $a_{n+1}+a_n$, and replace **one** of the $a_{n+1}$ by $a_n+a_{n-1}$. After a small amount of calculation we get
$$a_{n+2}a_n -a_{n+1}^2=-\left(a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-a_n^2\right),$$
which shows that the alternation of signs occurs.

The fact that $a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2$ has absolute value $1$ can then be used to  prove convergence. For note that it says that
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}-\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| =\frac{1}{a_na_{n+1}}.$$ Thus the absolute value of the difference of the ratios is shrinking rapidly.

Answer (score 2):

So here's a nice explanation of why the ratio is what it is.  Note, this isn't yet a satisfactory explanation of why it converges in the first place, but it's a nice starting point.

Suppose that there's some number $L$ so that $\dfrac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}}\to L$ as $n\to\infty$.  We note that at any $n$, we have
$$
F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}
$$
Dividing through by $F_{n-1}$, we get that
$$
\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}=1+\frac{F_{n-2}}{F_{n-1}}
$$
Which means that whatever our limit is, it should obey
$$
L = 1+\frac1L
$$
Rearranging, this gives us $L^2-L+1=0$,
Which has the solution
$$
L=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt 5}{2}
$$
Since only the positive solution makes sense for us, we find that the limit that this sequence approaches (if it's anything) should be $L=\frac12(1+\sqrt 5)\approx 1.618$ (also known as the golden ratio).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really special of the Fibonacci series, one can construct a whole class of series that wobble like this, from the iteration  $t_{n+1}=c\cdot t_n + t_{n-1}$.

A classical example is the iterations that produce the octagonal series, which equates to $c=2$ and converges on the alternating ratio $1+\sqrt{2}=2.414213456238$.

```
       1      1         1,000000           a        b
       2      3         1.500000           c=a+b    d=a+c
       5      7         1.400000
      12     17         1.416666
      29     41         1.413793
      70     90         1.414285
```

The main reason that this happens is that the approximation is of the form $a^n c + b^n d$, where variously $b$ abd $d$ might be negative, with $b<1$.  What one gets is an approximation $\frac{a^{n+1}c+e}{a^nc-e}$. which is slightly larger, and then $\frac{a^{n+1}c-e}{a^nc+e}$ which is slightly smaller.

In the Fibonacci series, we have $b=-0.61803398875, d=-1/\sqrt{5}$, in the series above, the value of $b=\sqrt{2}-1=-0.41421356$ suffices to cause this alternation.

Answer (score -1):

Let $F_i$ be the $i$-th Fibonacci number. Put $F_i$ people at one table, and deliver $F_{i-1}$ pizzas to them. Put $F_{i+1}$ people at a second table and deliver $F_i$ pizzas to them. At the first table, there are $F_{i-1}/F_i$ pizzas per person, and at the second table there are $F_i/F_{i+1}$ pizzas per person.

Now have everyone at the first table move to the second table, and bring their pizzas along. In total, there are $F_i + F_{i+1} = F_{i+2}$ people and $F_{i-1} + F_i = F_{i+1}$ pizzas, so we have $F_{i+1}/F_{i+2}$ pizzas per person. If there were more pizzas per person at the first table than at the second (in other words, if $F_{i-1}/F_i > F_i/F_{i+1}$), then bringing over the people from the first table *increased* the number of pizzas per person at the second table. In other words, $F_{i+1}/F_{i+2} > F_i/F_{i+1}$. If there were more pizzas per person at the second table ($F_{i-1}/F_i < F_i/F_{i+1}$), then bringing over the people from the first table *decreased* the number of pizzas per person, and $F_{i+1}/F_{i+2} < F_i/F_{i+1}$. This shows the oscillation. Note that either way, $F_{i+1}/F_{i+2}$ sits in between $F_{i-1}/F_i$ and $F_i/F_{i+1}$. The sequence of ratios converges by the alternating series test.

I phrased this in terms of ratios smaller than $1$ to avoid the appearance of gluttony, but obviously you can do the same thing with ratios greater than $1$ ($F_{i+1}/F_i$), or just take reciprocals.